# from differential geometry to complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

I'm an undergraduate in physics and all I know about the classical complex analysis is Cauchy's integral formula and residue theorem. I'm recently reading John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, and it seems OK to apply Stokes' theorem directly to complex functions on complex plane $\mathbb{C}\simeq\mathbb{R}^2$ , then one obtains the whole theory of complex analysis. Is there any textbook or lecture note concerning this topic?

Comment: I think that this is the approach of most complex analysis texts when proving the residue theorem in full generality.

Comment: In differential geometry, one usually assumes very strong smoothness hypotesis (everything is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ or $\mathcal{C}^k$). You can apply those results to the complex plane, but you'll miss out on stronger forms of the results, e.g. Cauchy's theorem for rectifiable curves.